# Cannot see data in view page source even though Cache of Apollo Client have data

Tags: graphql, next.js, apollo-client

I don't know why in another page, I use this way just different query and I can see data in view page source, but in this page, it does not work. I wondering it cause I use localStorage value as params, I don't think problem come from query.

```
interface Props {
  __typename?: 'ProductOfBill';
  amount: number,
  name: string,
  totalPrice: number,
  type: string,
  unitPrice: number,
}

const Cart = () => {
  const [products,setProducts] = useState<Props[]>([])
  const { data } = useGetSomeProductQuery({
    variables: { productList: productListForBill()},
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true
  });
  
  useEffect(() =>{

    if(data?.getSomeProduct){
     setProducts(data.getSomeProduct)
    }
    
  },[data])
  
  return (
    <>
      ...
    </>
  );
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const apolloClient = initializeApollo();
    await apolloClient.query<GetSomeProductQuery>({
      query: GetSomeProductDocument,
      variables: { productList: productListForBill() },
    });
    return addApolloState(apolloClient, {
      props: {},
    });
};

export default Cart;
```

I get localStorage value from this method.

```
export const productListForBill = () : GetProductForBill[] =>{
    const returnEmtpyArray : GetProductForBill[] = []
    if(typeof window !== "undefined"){
        if(localStorage.getItem("products"))
        {
            const tempProduct = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products") || "")
            if(Array.isArray(tempProduct)){
                return tempProduct
            }
        }   
    }
    return returnEmtpyArray
}
```

and I custom Apollo Client like doc of Nextjs in github

```
import { useMemo } from 'react'
import { ApolloClient, HttpLink, InMemoryCache, NormalizedCacheObject } from '@apollo/client'

import merge from 'deepmerge'
import isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual'

export const APOLLO_STATE_PROP_NAME = '__APOLLO_STATE__'

interface IApolloStateProps {
    [APOLLO_STATE_PROP_NAME]?: NormalizedCacheObject
}
let apolloClient : ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>
function createApolloClient() {
  return new ApolloClient({
    //type of "window"=== undefined
    ssrMode:  true,
    link: new HttpLink({
        uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
        credentials: "include",
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
   )}
  }
export function initializeApollo(initialState : NormalizedCacheObject | null = null) {
  const _apolloClient = apolloClient ?? createApolloClient()
  if (initialState) {
    const existingCache = _apolloClient.extract()
cache
    const data = merge(existingCache, initialState, {
      arrayMerge: (destinationArray, sourceArray) => [
        ...sourceArray,
        ...destinationArray.filter((d) =>
          sourceArray.every((s) => !isEqual(d, s))
        ),
      ],
    })

    _apolloClient.cache.restore(data)
  }
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') return _apolloClient
  if (!apolloClient) apolloClient = _apolloClient

  return _apolloClient
}

export function addApolloState(client :  ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>, pageProps: { props: IApolloStateProps }) {
  if (pageProps?.props) {
    pageProps.props[APOLLO_STATE_PROP_NAME] = client.cache.extract()
  }
  
  return pageProps
}

export function useApollo(pageProps : IApolloStateProps) {
  const state = pageProps[APOLLO_STATE_PROP_NAME]
  const store = useMemo(() => initializeApollo(state), [state])
  return store
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering

> Cannot see data in view page source even though Cache of Apollo Client have data

These are client side methods, value will not be visible in view source but in evaluated source, look in the elements panel in chrome.